# The editor wrote the paper for me

Tags: soft-question, journals

I submitted a short paper and received a positive review and a negative review. The editor (he) briefly wrote the following things:

1. He thinks my original result could be mistaken because of XYZ
2. He presents an alternative theorem (not entirely in mathematical language but with a combination of math and English), which gives a finer result than mine
3. He presents a sketch of proof
4. He presents an example
5. He adds that, if I think he is wrong, and I was right, please revise my manuscript addressing concerns of reviewers and submit again.

I thought I was right, but after working on this topic for a few more months, I find that he is actually correct. So I wrote down his theorem, proofs, and example in details. I am about to submit, but an idea jumps into my head: he should own the copyright, not me. What should I do here?

*Background*: he is a very smart and cutting-edge researcher in my field, but he does not work on the problems in my direction, so I won't be plagiarizing his papers.

Comment: You could ask him to be a co-author.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I thought since he own the copyright, I should ask him if he is willing to include me as a coauthor? Or does my wording sound too weird?

Comment: If you can, you should ask your advisor for advice. If you can’t, ask the editor if they would like to be a co-author on the revised article. If they say “no” then you should thank them in the acknowledgments.

Comment: As I understand copyright law it does not apply to ideas, but to the expression of ideas in concrete form (music scores, photographs, written work…) So the editor might own the copyright on the email they sent you, but not the copyright on the revised paper. If you extensively and directly quote the email then the revised paper might be called a “derived work” and the editor would have certain claims they could make.

Comment: But generally, in academia and prepublication, all of that is ignored and we use different rules. Post publication the journals own the copyrights and act as rentiers, charging everybody for access.

Comment: Copyright is all but irrelevant here. The problem is authorship. You can’t just use his ideas as if they were your own.

Comment: In regards to your comment, you can phrase the request in such a way that it does not specify if you have the right to claim authorship of the paper and are generously including him, or he has the right to claim authorship and is generously including you, or neither has a right to exclude the other, or any other moral stance.

Comment: This is the advantage of Timothy Chow's language "propose that you and he be coauthors of the paper" or something like "I would like to submit a new version of the article I submitted, based on your email to me, with you as a coauthor. Would this work for you?"

Comment: I agree with all the suggestions to ask the editor to be a co-author. If the editor says no, it would definitely be polite to ask if he would mind you publishing the stronger result with an acknowledgment of his help. But you should not discount your own original contribution, without which the editor might not have thought of the stronger result, plus your work in writing out the details of the editor's sketch. I'd be curous if others disagree, but I think it would be appropriate to provide a short outline of this history in the introduction to the new version, explaining both contributions.

Comment: Also, even if the editor does not want to be a co-author, you might show them the new version and ask them to approve of it before submitting elsewhere. Depending on the personality of the editor, he might even be a good resource for suggesting where to submit it.

Comment: I applaud you for caring about this. Even if your concern is entirely due to fear of potential consequences, which isn't the vibe I get from your question, you still get bonus points from me.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[Comments combined into a community wiki answer.]

*Copyright* is the wrong word in this context; the correct word is *authorship*.  A reasonable course of action is to propose to the editor that you and he be coauthors of the paper.  If the editor agrees, then the paper would need to be re-submitted to a different journal; it would be a conflict of interest for the editor to accept his own paper for publication.  If the editor declines, then the editor's contribution should be formally acknowledged in the paper, and you can proceed with the publication process.

Comment: Right. Re-submit to a different journal to avoid conflict-of-interest stuff.

Comment: Or the editor could have someone else in the board handle that submission. This is also a common approach and there is no need to submit to a different venue if the option is available.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Sure, that's common and greatly reduces the conflict of interest, but there still may be some conflict of interest, especially if all editors vote on final decisions.  Certainly there's more potential for perception of conflict of interest.

Comment: @Kimball: Why can't they simply check that that editor's votes did not affect the outcome (i.e. final set of accepted papers), and if so then a consensus has to be reached regarding the final outcome?

Comment: If the editor becomes a coauthor, I think you can trust his judgement on whether submitting the paper to his coeditors would be too much of a conflict of interest for him or not.